# Browser Error on low performance machines

Tags: silverlight, plugins, browser

ai make an silverlight image uploader the code is running ok, but on a low performance machines the browser(Firefox,Chrome) give an error like this: The plugin 'silverlight' is not responding!!, the resize method have a cpu cost and cause problem.

I need to now this think's:

- Have one way to set this "Check Plugin TimeOut" on a browser?
- Have one way to load files with OpenFileDialog assync?

  ```
  private void btnSelectFiles_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {

      files = new List<File>();

      OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
      dlg.Multiselect = Parameters.multiselect;
      dlg.Filter = Parameters.filter;

      if (dlg.ShowDialog() == true)
      {
          JavaScriptHelper.Invoke("SilverUploaderDebug", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + " - Abrindo arquivos");

          foreach (var file in dlg.Files)
          {
              try
              {

                  var f = new File();
                  JavaScriptHelper.Invoke("SilverUploaderDebug", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + " - Abrindo " + file.Name);

                  JavaScriptHelper.Invoke("SilverUploaderDebug", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + " - Redimensionando " + file.Name + "(grande)");
                  var stream1 = file.OpenRead();
                  f.data1 = ImageHelper.Resize(stream1, Parameters.img_width, Parameters.img_height, 90, f);
                  JavaScriptHelper.Invoke("SilverUploaderDebug", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + " - OK");

                  JavaScriptHelper.Invoke("SilverUploaderDebug", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + " - Redimensionando " + file.Name + "(pequeno)");
                  var stream2 = file.OpenRead();
                  f.data2 = ImageHelper.Resize(stream2, Parameters.img_thumb_width, Parameters.img_thumb_height, 90, f);
                  JavaScriptHelper.Invoke("SilverUploaderDebug", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + " - OK");                        

                  f.name = file.Name;
                  f.extension = file.Extension;
                  files.Add(f);
                  JavaScriptHelper.Invoke("SilverUploaderFileLoaded",JsonHelper.SerializeToJsonString(f));
              }
              catch(Exception ex)
              {
                  JavaScriptHelper.Invoke("SilverUploaderException", ex.Message);
              }
          }

          if (Parameters.auto_upload)
              upload();
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The reason the Silverlight plugin is "not responding" is that you're running long-running operations on the UI thread. Why not move the actual reading of image files (`file.OpenRead()`), and manipulation of those, onto a `BackgroundWorker`? I don't know what your `upload` method does, hopefully it's nice and asynchronous, but you might want to think whether that's taking a non-trivial time too.

If you want to improve the user experience you can then try adding a "work in progress" indication on the UI while your background thread chugs along.